# How can I pull information from spreadsheets in multiple folders in google script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I already have a script which references all documents in ONE folder, but I need to reference multiple folders...

Script that works for one folder is:

```
var folder = DocsList.getFolder("My Spreadsheets");
var contents = folder.getFiles();
```

What I WANT to do is either

```
var masterfolder = DocsList.getFolder("My Folder that has multiple folders");
var folder = DocsList.getFolders(masterfolder)
var contents = folder.getFiles();
```

or

```
 var folder = DocsList.getFolder("My Spreadsheets", "My Other Spreadsheets");
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
```

Comment: Wrote a little [exapmle](https://sites.google.com/a/lagaroo.com.br/dev-test/dev-test/dev-test-multiple-folders) to get you giong!

Answer (score 0):

I am quite newbye in this, but I think you'll have to do an iteration throught the subfolders:

var folder = DocsList.getFolders(masterfolder)
    Here you dont't get one single folder; you get a set of them and you have to iterate trhout it with a for bucle. Something like:
for f in folders {
     f.getfiles......
     ...
     }

SURE you will get more precise answer.

Enrique